# 0.56inch 7segment display failure

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I am Nikhil from India, working as an embedded programmer. I made half inch 7segment display based digital clock. But after few months few 7segment displays got damaged. I got same complaints in many boards. Please help me to debug the error.

5v dc power supply is used.Pic16f877a is used for controlling.74hc164 is the shift register ic used.

Bd140 transistor is used for on/off 7segment display.

5v is connected to the emitter of bd140.

Base is connected to pic microcontroller via resistor.Collector is connected to common anode of 7segment display.Cathode pins are connected to 74hc164 via current limiting resistors.

I think this is the recommended connecting method. But around 1/10th of the total segments used are getting damaged within few months.

I used 560e as current limiting resistor and increased its value upto 2k2, but no change only brightness is getting down.

Comment: Are you sure that the damage isn't mechanical, rather than electrical? Perhaps you have bad solder joints or poor quality PCBs whose traces are cracking.

Comment: I already used the same design for 1inch 7segment display, and its works fine.

Comment: Whatever current limiting resistors used, the forward voltage drop of 7segment is above 2v. So for reducing the forward voltage drop,  i am redesigning my circuit which uses 3v3  power supply for 7segment operation and 5v for pic microcontroller. I am not sure how much successful it will be.

Comment: Is it the same brand/model of 7-segment in each case? Circuit schematic and 7-segment datasheets would be useful.

Comment: Have you seen any patterns in the damaged segments?

Comment: Have you tested your power supply for spikes, especially during turn on?

Comment: I used 4-5 brands of segments, but result is same.

Comment: What environment is this "digital clock" used in? For an oven or refrigeration system?

Comment: We are using it for displaying the praytimes in mosque. So its working environment is normal

Comment: Also the power supply may be a problem, 230v -12v adapter + lm7805 based power supply with filter capacitor is using

Comment: Doesn't find any patterns on damaged segments, damaged segments will be dim or always glow lightly even if common anode pin is low

Answer (score 1):

Years ago one of my designs once experienced similar unexplained failures- it turned out that the assembly house was using resistor packs marked 470 which were actually 47\$\Omega\$! The excess current caused segment failures, especially in hot industrial environments. Naturally this was also a wake-up call for their inspection and testing.

Failing the above, I would suggest bad quality displays, but that's fairly rare.

Edit: **If** they are failing just as often with 2.2K resistors (and *your* PCBs are not faulty, clean, dry and uncontaminated) then the **displays are faulty**, no way around it. Make sure you're getting first quality parts. One possibility is that the internal double-sided PCBs have faulty plated through holes which are cracking at the edges. I've seen that in bare PCBs when the PCB manufacturer has poor control over their process. The display manufacturer (many of which in China are smallish companies) would have known this (high fallout rate) and may have shipped the parts anyway to a customer who demanded the very lowest price (your supplier?). Just a thought.

Edit2: Since you say you've tried several brands, then we're kind of left with some problem with your PCBs or the environment they are in. LEDs are not very fragile electrically and can withstand a lot of short-term abuse without failure, and your descriptions do not indicate anything remotely dubious electrically.

Comment: @PeterJ Yes, might not be, but I've done enough field service to know how much to weight such comments. My favorite was the instrument that "just stopped working". The fact it had a fork-lift tine run halfway through the housing wasn't mentioned.

Comment: I used 2k2 resistor of carbon film type and metal film type, but result is same. Theoretically 2k2 resistor is too high for a 7segment display to work in 5v supply rails. Also working environment is not industrial, just normal room temperature.

Comment: @Nikhil Please see my edit above, expanding on my previous last point. No resistor is really "too high" (just too dim maybe) but 2.2K is really conservative.

Comment: Display failure means its not completely off. Some segments will glow dimmer compared to other segments. And some segments will glow even if its common anode pin is low.

Comment: @Nikhil Could also be something to do with contamination or wire bonding. Anyway, it's not our business to figure out the problems for the LED guys. Have you actually examined the instruments for failure analysis to ensure they're not getting wet or something silly like that? I've also seen similar weird failures when contaminated water is run over PCBs. The traces get eaten away and conductive residue is deposited.

Comment: I am using single sided pcb. And your point on quality might be a cause. I am getting it for under 4 Indian rupee, which is cheaper. But i took segments from different states in india, result is same. I just want to know whether my design is ok or not. We used to manufacture clocks professionally with 1 inch and 2.3inch displays. Only 0.56 inch design failed. Any thanks for your comments

Comment: About 6 cents US for the PCB is indeed pretty cheap even for a single sided board- check that the pads are not being lifted and broken off where the traces join. That can happen if pressure is put on the front of the display and the adhesive holding the traces to the board is weak (or from sloppy assembly work such as when leads are trimmed). Paper phenolic boards can also crack easily from outside forces and that can cause all kinds of intermittent problems. Probably a bit less of a problem in a warm climate.

Comment: After designing i started its production commercially. And after sale , costumers started calling that the display is damaged. So its not with the track breaking or handling

Comment: Is there any way to upload the circuit diagram